# Sharding and managing very busy variable

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have one variable `pool`, shared by all clients, that stores all remaining enemies in a game.  When a client starts a game, he gets some enemies from `pool`.  When he finishes, enemies that he did not kill are put back into `pool`.  The game also checks to see if all the enemies have been killed (i.e., `pool` is empty).

What is the best way to implement `pool`?  I'm concerned about the 5 updates per second limit on a datastore entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How often do expect a game to be started/finished?  If the answer is definitely less than 5 per second, then just use a single entity to represent `pool` and use transactions to atomically get and update it as games start and finish.

If you're really expecting so many clients to share a single `pool` that it will be updated at a sustained rate of more that 5 times per second, then consider sharding `pool` into multiple pieces.  When the client starts a game, remove entities from just one of the shards.  To test if the sharded `pool` is empty, just retrieve all the shards and see if they are all empty.  (When modifying a shard, you'll still need to use a transaction.)

Comment: +1 You could optimize a little by only retrieving a subset of shards to see if a shard still has enemies, and thus the pool is not empty.